# How to properly mount other partitions (NTFS) on my Fedora FSH?

Tags: fedora, fstab, readonly, uuid, ntfs-3g

I recently switched to Fedora 27 Beta (UEFI install, dual-boot with Win 10), and I changed my `/etc/fstab` to include the two following lines:

```
UUID=D0E24ECDE24EB78C /media/DownloadsBin  ntfs-3g  auto,user,rw,x-gvfs-show  0 0
UUID=4E565C9C565C869D /media/VMs           ntfs-3g  auto,user,rw,x-gvfs-show  0 0
```

It should have loaded the devices bearing the given UUIDs into `/media/DownloadsBin` and `/media/VMs` appropriately **with rw permissions**, right? Well, since these are Windows partitions, I had to mount them using NTFS-3g. I can see the files, but whenever I even try to create a new folder (e.g. using `mkdir test`), I get the error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Read-only file system

The strange part is a similar script worked before on Fedora 26, although I'm not sure if it's got something to do with Fedora 27 Beta (a bug?!) or if there's an error in my code. So, I've come to ask the experts for help!

**NOTE** : I really don't want to mess around with partition or the folder permissions, especially changing the owner, since Windows started complaining and stopped me from writing to the disk the last time I tried this! I'm hoping there's a better way I can share entire partitions between Win 10 and Fedora 27 Beta without pissing either operating system off?!

---

Upon further investigation, it turns out that the partitions might be mounted as *read-only* as confirmed by `findmnt /media/(dir)`:

> [somu@lappyPrime DownloadsBin]$ findmnt /media/DownloadsBin TARGET
>   SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS /media/DownloadsBin /dev/sda5 fuseblk
>   ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
>   [somu@lappyPrime DownloadsBin]$ findmnt /media/VMs TARGET SOURCE
>   FSTYPE OPTIONS /media/VMs /dev/sda6 fuseblk
>   ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

Can anyone tell me what's going on?!

Comment: once mounted run mount -o remount rw  /mountpoint

Comment: Why do you use `ntfs-3g` and not `ntfs`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ntfs-3g is the available option for read-write access to ntfs.  `ntfs` is the kernel filesystem type, which only ever had experimental write support, I don't even know if it exists anymore because it's not very useful.

Comment: What happens if you unmount the FS and mount it manually? Does it show any warning?  Note, systemd did not save mount messages to the system log due to an oversight which I submitted a patch for a few days ago :).

Comment: @sourcejedi Er, ntfs is still around, still has write support and still works. AFAIK ntfs-3g is the outdated filesystem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton news to us! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ntfs https://wiki.debian.org/NTFS